# How to make laravel relations to work properly?

Tags: php, laravel, http, get

I am trying to get a object using the relations in laravel. In my project, 1 instalation belongs to 1 project and 1 project can have many installations. In the migration i have coded like this:

Projects:

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->string('name');
            $table->boolean('removed');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

Installations:

```
Schema::create('installations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->bigInteger('country_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('project_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('building_admin_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('name');

            $table->boolean('removed');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
            $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
            $table->foreign('building_admin_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

And in the models...

Installation:

```
   public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
```

Project:

```
public function installations(){
    return $this->hasMany(Installation::class);
}
```

The case is that i have a middleware to check that the author of the installation is the authenticated user by using:

```
 if($request->installation->project->user->id != Auth::user()->id){
            return back()->with('notAuthor', 'Access denied. You are not the owner of this installation.');
        }
        return $next($request);
```

And Laravel give me an error. I have check why, and doing `dd($request->installation)` i recieve the `installation_id` instead of the entire object.

The case is that i have used this middleware on the delete and modify installation methods, and it works, why in this case not?

I know that knowing the id of the installation i can get it by a query, but i want to know why this is not working, it have no sense for me..

If you need to see more of the code, text me.

Regards..

Comment: did you setup the relationship from Request to Installation?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer to me. I have not, how i should do that?? I am starting at laravel...

Comment: Assuming that you are talking about implicit model binding, the handle method will not resolve the injection. You might want to have a constructor in the middleware and then inject Installation class into the constructor, assign to class variable then access that from the handle method.

Comment: depends on the relationship ... looks like Request belongsTo Installation since it has the installation key on it

Comment: @anishsaud if they were using Route Model binding then they could get that binding from the Request in the middleware ... `$request->route('parameter')`

Comment: Hi, I have tried to set up the relation with Request and it works, but i do not have understand why works too with the edit and remove functions, if the relation wasn't setted up.

Comment: Thank you to all for wasting your time with me, hehe